# How to switch a word to a variable in when condition

Tags: variables, filter, ansible, conditional-statements

I'm using Ansible roles for create some VMs on vCenter.

My role works well, but I would like to make more dynamic playbooks.

In my sitation, I have vars/main.yml with this vars :

```yaml
foldervm: /datacenter/vm/PROD/

vm1: thisismyfirstvm
vm2: thisismysecondvm
vm3: thisismythirdvm
vm4: thisismyfourthvm

array:
  - name: "{{ vm1 }}"
    cpu: 3
    memory: 84992
  - name: "{{ vm2 }}"
    cpu: 10
    memory: 20480
  - name: "{{ vm3 }}"
    cpu: 4
    memory: 8192
  - name: "{{ vm4 }}"
    cpu: 8
    memory: 65536
```

And a tasks/createlvmpart.yml like that :

```yaml
- name: parted /dev/sdc
  vmware_vm_shell:

    hostname: "{{ ip_vcenter }}"
    username: "{{ username_vcenter }}"
    password: "{{ password_vcenter }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    validate_certs: no

    folder: "{{ foldervm }}"
    vm_id: "{{ item.name }}"
    vm_username: "{{ id }}"
    vm_password: "{{ pass }}"
    
    vm_shell: /usr/sbin/parted
    vm_shell_args: "-s /dev/sdc unit GB mkpart primary 50% 100% set 2 lvm on"

  with_items:
    - "{{ array }}"
  

  when: 
    - not item.name is search("thismysecond")
    - item.name != 'vm3'
```

My problem is in when condition.
I would like to make like this line:

```yaml
  when: not item.name is search("thismysecond")
```

but the word "thismysecond" is replace to his variable : "{{ vm2 }}".

I have tested this:

```yaml
  when: not item.name is search("{{ vm2 }}")
```

and this:

```yaml
  when: item.name != 'vm2'
```

But it doesn't work. My playbook don't apply the parted command on vm2, just for vm1, vm3 and vm4.

I have searched on the internet, but I think I formulated the question not well in my research because I didn't find the answer.

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: `when: item.name != vm2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Mark Rotteveel for your correction (Sorry for my bad English :( )

And thank you @β.εηοιτ.βε for your answer.

It's just problem of syntax, it's not:

> when: item.name != 'vm2'

But it's:

> when: item.name != vm2

It's works like a charm now!

Comment: Please note that questions related to typos are considered [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on this site and should be closed/deleted. You can delete you own question before this happens by votes.

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator, can't delete my question because somebody have answer to my question :/